# How do I extract Info associated with any OpenID provider?

Tags: php, openid

OpenID providers like GOogle,Yahoo etc also stroes user info like Name,email etc. Is it possible to retrieve it by using OpenID Selector(http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/)? If yes then how do I fetch it? is the OpenID URL same every time when a user logs in? if yes ten may I store that handler in DB?

I am using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

The Selector doesn't perform discovery or construction of the auth request URL.  So your RP server-side just gets an OpenID Identifier just as it would if you had an ordinary text box.  So I believe your question is more targeted at your specific PHP OpenID library rather than any special considerations due to the selector you're using.

If you need more help, you might want to edit your question to mention the name of the PHP library you're using.